# How to change direction of horizontal effect from rtl to ltr

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a **panelGrid** inside a **rtl** body and i am applying slide effect to one of the columns inside the **panelGrid** and the effect is applied from right to left, and i was wondering how to apply the effect from ltr.

herer's my code:

```
    <h:panelGrid id="closed_notebook" "columns="2">
        <h:panelGroup id="middle_closed" layout="block">
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup id="left_closed" layout="block">

            <h:outputLink id="open_book_link" value="javascript:void(0)"
                style="margin-right:110px;">
                <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/book.png" />


                <p:effect  speed="2000" for="closed_notebook" type="fold"
                    event="click" >
                    <f:param name="mode" value="'hide'" />
                </p:effect>

                <p:effect type="blind" event="click" for="open_notebook"
                    speed="1000" delay="500">
                    <f:param name="mode" value="'show'" />
                </p:effect>

            </h:outputLink>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<p:effect type="slide" event="click">
    <f:param name="direction" value="'left'">
</p:effect>
```

PrimeFaces effects using jQuery effects, so the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects) can be helpful about effect options.