# primefaces dialog slide effect

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using below primefaces dialog.

```
<p:commandButton value="Effects" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg3').show();" /> 


<p:dialog header="Effects" widgetVar="dlg3" showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide" height="100">
    <h:outputText value="This dialog has nice effects." />
</p:dialog>
```

slide working perfectly.
but i need slide right to left.
normally above effect work left to right.
how to i change slide direction?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change direction of horizontal effect from rtl to ltr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191184/how-to-change-direction-of-horizontal-effect-from-rtl-to-ltr)

Comment: thanks.that link was very helpful.